# Custom error message in search box jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I want to display a custom error message if the search field is empty. Please tell me how can I do it.

Comment: As in you type in a search value, search and there is no results returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can use [searchrules](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asearch_config#searchrules) inside of `colModel`. For example

```js
searchrules: {required: true}
```

Comment: Oleg, I am already using the searchrules as you say. But I want to display a custom message and not the one the jqgrid already provides.

Comment: @user1986736: In the case you can use `custom: true` inside `searchrules`. See documentation which provide [the corresponding example](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config#custom_checking_example)